# Is there a way to get a number value from a style type using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to integer value of the style.bottom element of one of my nodes using javascript. Im wondering if they is possible considering it outputs in pixel size.

i.e

```
 console.log(image.style.bottom)
```

this outputs say "100px"

I'm wondering if theres a way to get that value as an integer ive tried using

```
 console.log(Number(image.style.bottom))
```

but it returns isNaN so I'm wondering if theres a specific call that can do this

Comment: just use regex? Or just truncate the last two letters the Number it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ignores everything after and including the first non-digit character:

```
> parseInt("100px", 10)
100
```

Comment: thanks! that worked perfectly ill accept when the timer is up